# Same eigenvalue but different direction fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Determine which direction field corresponds to each linear system
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]

When I solve for the eigenvalues of the two linear systems I get both to be the imaginary number $i$ so the direction fields should look the same but they don't. The answer is $1=B$ and $2=C$ but I do not understand what makes them different?

I would appreciate if someone could explain how to obtain this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the point $\binom {5}{0}$ and compare the two vevtor fields at that point you notice that for (1) you have $\binom {5}{10}$ which corresponds to  $B$ and for $(2)$ it is $\binom {5}{-10}$ which corresponds to $(C)$

Comment: That was very clear and easy, thank you very much!